# Dynamically Instancing Objects ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a variable named "type".  And I want to instance an object with the name of the value of type.  Here is an example:

```
var myObjectName = "ball";
var object = new ball(); //Except I want to use the value of myObjectName.
```

I believe this used to be easy with AS2 when using _global, but I'm not sure how to do it in AS3?

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

First get the class object with `flash.utils.getDefinitionByName()`, then instantiate that object:

```
var myClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(myObjectName) as Class;
var object:Object = new myClass();
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName()